# Searching Twitter

Tags: php, json, curl, twitter

How can I make a simple search on Twitter through PHP, Java, or CURL JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Fetching JSON with Curl:

```
curl --data-urlencode "q=query here" http://search.twitter.com/search.json
```

See [Twitter's API Reference](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a nice REST API for searching. The docs are here:

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search

To search and get JSON back it's as easy as this:

```
$ curl http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackoverflow
{"results":[{"text":"Saturday night and I'm reading http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/ #dorkbot","to_user_id":.......
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way? http://twitter.com/#search?q=whatever - then substitute "whatever". You can use HttpClient's HttpGet for that in Java

You can add variations like "search API for user CNN" which would be
http://twitter.com/#search?q=source%3AAPI%20@cnn

If want RSS instead of HTML use (for above query)
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=source%3AAPI%20@cnn

And there's [the whole Spritzer API](http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/31/spritzer-your-twitter/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ladygaga&rpp=10'
```

is the simplest twitter command line option ever

```
$curl 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ladygaga&rpp=10' > filename.ext
```

this "pipes" it into a previously non-existent file called filename.ext (I like to think of it as filename.txt "eating" the output).

Answer (score 0):

First, you must register to be a twitter developer to gain access token, access token secret, consumer key, and consumer secret.
After that you can use OAuth to perform curl to the given REST API for search that twitter provide to us.
[documentation for search API in dev twittter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

Also, you could learn at my simple project on github : [Integrate-Services-With-Twitter-API-cURL-PHP](https://github.com/mczal/Integrate-Services-With-Twitter-API-cURL-PHP)